# Three PHP function files too many?

Tags: php

Basically notices are getting thrown up because the page is making calls to all three function files on one of my pages.

Each function page makes a call to a connection file

```
require("db_config.php");
```

So, is it better to bundle all my function files into one file so the call is only made once?

Or should I come up with some sort of conditional statement to make sure the require only runs once?

Thanks

Comment: use `require_once(string)`

Comment: Since you're new here, I'll give you a friendly warning: if you keep asking questions of such low quality, you will likely find yourself permanently banned from asking questions on Stack Overflow. Please take a look at [the Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 4):

Using [`require_once`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.require-once.php) (or [`include_once`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include-once.php)), you can make sure a file is only included once.

Answer (score 2):

It really depends on how these functions are used.

As other answers tell you, the `require_once(...)` will ensure that a particular file is only included once in your code. However, if one ALWAYS uses these three functions close together (or at least most of the time, use two or three at a time), then having them in the same file makes more sense than having them in individual files. On the other hand, if MOST of the time, you only use one, maybe two sometimes, and once in a while use all three, then having separate files will reduce the time it takes to load the page (by some tiny amount, but if you have lots of pages, that are loaded lots of times, small differences make a large amount of overall time).